# How to enable admin user of master realm

Tags: realm, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

KeyCloak Admin user of the master realm has been disabled my mistake. How can I enablae it ?

Expecting to enable the admin user so that I can login back.

Not sure if the user enable is happening anywhere in DB or need to have any cli command and the admin user is still active on the cli.

please healp

Comment: How can disabled admin through the user interface?

Comment: How does this question relate to Realm, part of MongoDB Realm, the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can log into the database and enable the user. Something like

```
select * from user_entity where realm_id='master';
update user_entity set enabled=true where realm_id='master';
```